# Orbifold Vector bundle from parabolic vector bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

I am reading the paper 'Parabolic Bundles as Orbifold bundles' by Indranil Biswas. In Sect. 3 of the paper, one starts with a Parabolic vector bundle and constructs a corresponding orbifold vector bundle on a suitable cover. I have a doubt in the construction which I explain as follows. For simplicity, I take the case of a rank two vector bundle with a parabolic structure along an irreducible smooth divisor.

Suppose $X$ is a connected smooth projective variety of dimension $n$ over $\mathbb{C}$. Assume that $D$ is a smooth and irreducible divisor on $X$. Suppose $E$ is a rank two vector bundle on $X$ which admits a Parabolic structure along $D$. That is there is a filtration 
 $$E|_D=F_1(E|_D)\supset F_2(E|_D)\supset F_3(E|_D)=0\,.$$
 Assume that

(1) $F_2(E|_D)$ is a line bundle and the quotient $\frac{F_1(E|_D)}{F_2(E|_D)}$ is a line bundle,

(2) the weights for simplicity are $\alpha_1=0$, $\alpha_2=\frac{m_2}{N}$.

By the Kawamata covering Lemma, there is a nonsingular connected projective variety $Y$ and a finite Galois morphism $p:Y\rightarrow X$ such that $\tilde{D}=(p^*D)_{red}$ and $p^*D=N\tilde{D}$. One way of constructing the orbifold bundle $W$ on $Y$ corresponding to the above parabolic bundle is given (in Page 313) as follows:

Consider the vector bundle $W_2=p^*E\otimes O_Y(m_2\tilde{D})$. Let $K_1$ denote the restriction of $p^*\Big(\frac{E|_D}{F_2(E|_D)}\otimes O_X(D)\Big)$ to $m_2\tilde{D}$. Then the paper says that 
there is a natural restriction map $W_2\rightarrow K_1$ which is surjective whose kernel is $W$.

I am not able to understand how we get this surjective map. It would be very helpful if someone can explain how to exactly get this surjective morphism, in this simple case.

I get a surjective restriction map from $W_2$ to $K_1\otimes O_Y(-(N-m_2)\tilde{D})|_{m_2\tilde{D}}$. I don't know how to get one from $W_2$ to $K_1$

Comment: Not an answer, but you may want to have a look at https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0604458 especially §3.4.2 .

Comment: @Niels, thanks! I will have someone translate this to English asap. So just out of curiosity now, does that section talk about this construction?

Comment: I'm not as familiar with Biswas' paper, but I think you just have to compose with $O_Y(-(N-m_2)\tilde{D})\to O_Y$ (restricted to $m_2\tilde{D}$).

Comment: @Mattia Talpo, sorry can you please elaborate. What do we need to compose with the map given by you?

Comment: @user349424 : yes this section gives a functor from parabolic sheaves to stacky sheaves "explicitly".

Comment: @user349424 I don't think I understand your question. For any effective Cartier divisor $D$ on a scheme $X$ you have a natural map $O_X(-D)\to O_X$ (the inclusion of the sheaf of ideals of $D$ in the structure sheaf).

Comment: @MattiaTalpo, that's right, that's why we get the map $O_Y(-(N-m_2)\tilde{D})\rightarrow O_Y$. I know that. This gives an inclusion $O_Y(m_2\tilde{D})\rightarrow O_Y(N\tilde{D})$. Composing this, we get a morphism $W_2\rightarrow K_1$. I need to show that this is surjective.

Comment: @user349424 I had a look at the paper, and I think you're just mixing up the indices. The assertion is that the natural map from $p^*(E\otimes O_X(D))$ to the restriction of $p^*(E|_D/F_2 \otimes O_X(D))$ to $(N-m_2)\tilde{D}$ is surjective, and this should be clear just from surjectivity of $E\to E|_D/F_2$.

Comment: @MattiaTalpo, I am talking about equation (3.4). Are you talking about equation (3.3)? I understand equation (3.3). My doubt is in equation (3.4)